# nested for loop query

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to do something rather simple, but can't seem to get it...

I have 3 cell-arrays with strings,

```
A = {'ConditionA'; 'ConditionB'; 'ConditionC'; 'ConditionD'};

B = {'Case1'; 'Case2'; 'Case3'; 'Case4'};

C = {'Rice'; 'Beans'; 'Carrots'; 'Cereal';'Tomato'; 'Cabbage';...
    'Sugar'}
```

I want to produce a vector with the concatenated (strcat?) combinations, as it this were a "tree diagram", like:

```
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(1))
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(2))
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(3))
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(4))
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(5))
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(6))
strcat(A(1),B(1),C(7))

strcat(A(1),B(2),C(1))
```

So what the first elements I am trying to get are (in a column ideally):

ConditionACase1Rice
ConditionACase1Beans
ConditionACase1Carrots
ConditionACase1Cereal
ConditionACase1Tomato
ConditionACase1Cabbage
ConditionACase1Sugar
ConditionACase2Rice
etc etc etc...

I know that:

```
for i=1:length(A)
    E(i) = strcat(A(i),B(1),C(1))
end
```

Works for one "level". I have tried:

```
for i=1:length(A)
    for j=1:length(B)
        for k=1:length(C)
            P(i) = strcat(A(i),B(j),C(k));
        end
    end
end
```

But this doesn't work...

I would be really grateful if I could be helped with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want all possible combinations of the strings of the input arrays as specified. If so, simply replace your nested loops with the following:

```
P = cell(length(A)*length(B)*length(C),1);
t=1;
for i=1:length(A)
    for j=1:length(B)
        for k=1:length(C)
            P(t) = strcat(A(i),B(j),C(k));
            t = t+1;
        end
    end
end
```

For the input arrays,

```
>> A = {'ConditionA'; 'ConditionB'; 'ConditionC'; 'ConditionD'};
>> B = {'Case1'; 'Case2'; 'Case3'; 'Case4'};
>> C = {'Rice'; 'Beans'; 'Carrots'; 'Cereal';'Tomato'; 'Cabbage';'Sugar'};
```

The value of P would be:

```
>> P

P = 

    'ConditionACase1Rice'
    'ConditionACase1Beans'
    'ConditionACase1Carrots'
    'ConditionACase1Cereal'
    'ConditionACase1Tomato'
    'ConditionACase1Cabbage'
    'ConditionACase1Sugar'
    'ConditionACase2Rice'
    'ConditionACase2Beans'
    'ConditionACase2Carrots'
    'ConditionACase2Cereal'
    'ConditionACase2Tomato'
    'ConditionACase2Cabbage'
    'ConditionACase2Sugar'
    'ConditionACase3Rice'
    'ConditionACase3Beans'
    'ConditionACase3Carrots'
    'ConditionACase3Cereal'
    'ConditionACase3Tomato'
    'ConditionACase3Cabbage'
    'ConditionACase3Sugar'
    'ConditionACase4Rice'
    'ConditionACase4Beans'
    'ConditionACase4Carrots'
    'ConditionACase4Cereal'
    'ConditionACase4Tomato'
    'ConditionACase4Cabbage'
    'ConditionACase4Sugar'
    'ConditionBCase1Rice'
    'ConditionBCase1Beans'
    'ConditionBCase1Carrots'
    'ConditionBCase1Cereal'
    'ConditionBCase1Tomato'
    'ConditionBCase1Cabbage'
    'ConditionBCase1Sugar'
    'ConditionBCase2Rice'
    'ConditionBCase2Beans'
    'ConditionBCase2Carrots'
    'ConditionBCase2Cereal'
    'ConditionBCase2Tomato'
    'ConditionBCase2Cabbage'
    'ConditionBCase2Sugar'
    'ConditionBCase3Rice'
    'ConditionBCase3Beans'
    'ConditionBCase3Carrots'
    'ConditionBCase3Cereal'
    'ConditionBCase3Tomato'
    'ConditionBCase3Cabbage'
    'ConditionBCase3Sugar'
    'ConditionBCase4Rice'
    'ConditionBCase4Beans'
    'ConditionBCase4Carrots'
    'ConditionBCase4Cereal'
    'ConditionBCase4Tomato'
    'ConditionBCase4Cabbage'
    'ConditionBCase4Sugar'
    'ConditionCCase1Rice'
    'ConditionCCase1Beans'
    'ConditionCCase1Carrots'
    'ConditionCCase1Cereal'
    'ConditionCCase1Tomato'
    'ConditionCCase1Cabbage'
    'ConditionCCase1Sugar'
    'ConditionCCase2Rice'
    'ConditionCCase2Beans'
    'ConditionCCase2Carrots'
    'ConditionCCase2Cereal'
    'ConditionCCase2Tomato'
    'ConditionCCase2Cabbage'
    'ConditionCCase2Sugar'
    'ConditionCCase3Rice'
    'ConditionCCase3Beans'
    'ConditionCCase3Carrots'
    'ConditionCCase3Cereal'
    'ConditionCCase3Tomato'
    'ConditionCCase3Cabbage'
    'ConditionCCase3Sugar'
    'ConditionCCase4Rice'
    'ConditionCCase4Beans'
    'ConditionCCase4Carrots'
    'ConditionCCase4Cereal'
    'ConditionCCase4Tomato'
    'ConditionCCase4Cabbage'
    'ConditionCCase4Sugar'
    'ConditionDCase1Rice'
    'ConditionDCase1Beans'
    'ConditionDCase1Carrots'
    'ConditionDCase1Cereal'
    'ConditionDCase1Tomato'
    'ConditionDCase1Cabbage'
    'ConditionDCase1Sugar'
    'ConditionDCase2Rice'
    'ConditionDCase2Beans'
    'ConditionDCase2Carrots'
    'ConditionDCase2Cereal'
    'ConditionDCase2Tomato'
    'ConditionDCase2Cabbage'
    'ConditionDCase2Sugar'
    'ConditionDCase3Rice'
    'ConditionDCase3Beans'
    'ConditionDCase3Carrots'
    'ConditionDCase3Cereal'
    'ConditionDCase3Tomato'
    'ConditionDCase3Cabbage'
    'ConditionDCase3Sugar'
    'ConditionDCase4Rice'
    'ConditionDCase4Beans'
    'ConditionDCase4Carrots'
    'ConditionDCase4Cereal'
    'ConditionDCase4Tomato'
    'ConditionDCase4Cabbage'
    'ConditionDCase4Sugar'
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Dear Roney Michael, thats exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! (PS. the names here are just pseudo names for what I am doing; its not an animal diet!)

Answer (score 0):

{

```
x = 1;
    for i=1:length(A)
        for j=1:length(B)
            for k=1:length(C)
                P(x) = strcat(A(i),B(j),C(k));
                x = x + 1;
            end
        end
    end

}
```

Please basically check your code before posting to PO as this is a very simple debugging

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for your help. I am using MATLAB, and I can't find any syntax as <x++> as mentioned above.

Please bear in mind that debugging can only be done by people who know what they are doing...I'm not being lazy here, I'm genuinely stuck with this problem. 

Any further help would be great, as this doesn't solve it yet...

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with matlab.. but maybe try something like this?

```
for A = {'ConditionA'; 'ConditionB'; 'ConditionC'; 'ConditionD'};
   for B = {'Case1'; 'Case2'; 'Case3'; 'Case4'};
     for  C = {'Rice'; 'Beans'; 'Carrots'; 'Cereal';'Tomato'; 'Cabbage'; 'Sugar'}
       P(i) = strcat(A(i),B(j),C(k));
    end
   end
  end
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help, but this was very similar to what I had that was unsuccessful...it seems that the index has to be updated within the innermost for loop, as shown below. At least in MATLAB...

Many thanks once again.